# Where do I need to put the Okta SAML IdP Metadata .xml file in my Custom Java application?

Tags: java, xml, saml, okta

I am currently in the process of using Okta's SAML Java Toolkit to enable SAML within a custom Java application.

I have generated the IdP Metadata in the Admin section of Okta, but am unsure of where I need to place it in my Java application.

I am using a weblogic server to test the program locally. Where would I place the .xml file containing the IdP metadata in order for SAMLRequests and SAMLResponses to gather the correct information?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The elements of IdP metadata are used in Custom SP Java application during runtime. If you can hook various elements of IdP metadata into your custom SP application, then you don't have to place IdP metadata anywhere in your application.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a URL that points to a metadata.xml file. The link pointing to the metadata file is utilized in Okta's Spring Security SAML toolkit for Java apps. This is detailed on our site: http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/spring_security_saml.html#configuring-spring-security-saml-to-work-with-okta

See Step 10.